# how to not blocking loop in windows form

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, .net-4.0

i'm pretty new in the .net programming and i would like to get some suggestions. 
I'm trying to create an easy client GUI application using the VS2010 Designer to create a single form in which i have:
1 comboBox, (containing the list of possible commands)
1 button, (used to execute the command selected in the combobox)
1 picturebox (in which i display images received from my server application)
I was able to create my client application and display a different image in the picturebox received from the server everytime i press the button.

What i would like to do is a not blocking loop in the event button click so that as long as the the client combobox command is set to start imaging, the images sent by the server are displayed in the picturebox and it stops when the client combobox command is set to stop imaging.

I'm not sure about how to do that because if i try and loop in the event button click, the GUI becomes unresponsive and i don't have a chance to change the command in the combobox.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Show some relevant code. You are probably using the wrong control to select (why a combo box??). To fix something, we need to know where to fix ;)

Comment: Hi,i was able to realize a not blocking loop by using a different thread.
I have a EthThread in which the client asks/receives data to/from the server and everytime and imagePacket is received a PictureRefresh() method is called.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "cheap" way to update the GUI by using the ReportProgress feature of the BackgroundWorker class.  First drop a BackgroundWorker object on your form.  Then...

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += DoWork;          
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += UpdateGui;
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
    }          
}
void UpdateGui(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```